# Left Align a label or any control in code

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, webforms

I've created another header row for a gridview programmatically. In this row I have a few controls including a label that I want to align all the way to the left of the cell. The one cell has a columnspan of 7 so it runs across the entire gridview. how do i align that label programmatically??

```
  Dim cell As New TableCell
  Dim lblfilter As New Label
  Dim row As New GridViewRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal)
    GridView1.Rows(0).Parent.Controls.AddAt(0, row)

lblfilter.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.AntiqueWhite    
cell.Controls.Add(lblfilter)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set Docking to Left in code you should be able to achieve that.

in C#:

```
lblfilter.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
```

That should dock it to the left of whatever container it is in.

Comment: Didn't work. It doesn't have a dock attribute. Thanks though.

Comment: Are you sure?  The System.Windows.Forms.Label Control does have a Dock attribute (just checked myself).  Are you using something different?

Comment: Yeah, for whatever reason it doesn't have that attribute. I even tried importing system.windows.forms.label

Comment: It should. Try to change your line to: 

Dim lblfilter As New Windows.Forms.Label

Comment: Ok. I get the attribute but I can't Add the label to the Grid's new row. 
Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.Control'.

here's how i add it:

cell.Controls.Add(lblfilter)

Comment: The Dock attribute is not a valid attribute for the Label defined in ASP.Net. This valid only for WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

you can try setting a css style to the label. Here is an example:

```
.leftLabel
{
float: left;
}
```

and then you set the style to the label like this:

```
lblfilter.CssClass = "leftLabel"
```